# binary code of php (compiling php)

Tags: php, compilation, binary

As you know php code doesn't compile to run,they are only script.
but I heard somewhere if I compile it and make it as binary code,it can be so faster and reduce pressure on server.
I Google a lot to do it,but I can't find a way to do it.
how can I do it?

Comment: PHP compiles since PHP4 (Zend Engine 1) into Bytecode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP compiles scripts into bytecodes, which can be cached, greatly speeding performance. Check out [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC).

Here's a list of other accelerators:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators

If you're looking to compile to native code, you can check out solutions like [HipHop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_%28software%29), which transforms PHP source into C++ and then compiles it with g++.

Answer (score 3):

[HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) is a “source code transformer” designed to reduce CPU and memory usage by transforming your PHP code into C++ code.

Comment: May I know why this has been downvoted. This take PHP into compiled language that is C++...

Answer (score 3):

You probably read of Facebook's [Hip Hop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php)

> HipHop was created by Facebook to save resources on its servers. It is
>   being distributed with its over 300,000 lines of source code written
>   in C++ and C as free software under the terms of version 3.01 of the
>   PHP License.

This [guy](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/04/02/hiphop-for-php-bechmark-english-version/) did a benchmark. Milliseconds for the 2nd and 3rd columns

```
Test name                PHP         HipHop            Ratio
n-body              754.474136     360.381707        209,35%
fannkuch-redux      3545.183693    1360.819455       260,52%
fasta               138.252463     55.924453         247,21%
spectral-norm       238.810613     93.717688         254,81%
mandelbrot          1532.191153    569.224470        269,17%
binary-trees (16)   37.286621      11.450954         325,62%
binary-trees (20)   1020.273547    249.907754        408,26%
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [php accelerator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator). [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) is widely used.